How to create Custom Rich TextEditor in a Flutter App?
I am working on a app where user can type something in a Textformfield and can also apply different kind of style on it.
Kindly check below image for the same.
Rich Text Editor in App 
I have checked available plugins like Flutter Quill and fleather.
Still not able to achieve.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Flutter Quill can achieve that, you just need to explore around it a little more, then show us what you tried

I guess, @Texv is right; you can customize flutter_quill by yourself. And if you need help, just post it here in SO.

Creating a Rich Text Editor in a Flutter application that allows users to type and apply different styles (e.g., bold, italic, underline) can be tricky. While plugins like Flutter Quill and Fleather are great, they might not always meet custom requirements. If you’re facing challenges with those, here are some alternative approaches:
Custom Solution Using RichText and TextSpan
If you need more flexibility or a lightweight solution, you can build your own rich text editor using Flutter’s RichText and TextSpan.
Here’s a basic example:

Create a custom TextEditingController to store styled text data.

Use a combination of TextField and RichText to display the input and apply styles dynamically.
Example:



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RichTextEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RichTextEditorState createState() => _RichTextEditorState();
}

class _RichTextEditorState extends State<RichTextEditor> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  bool _isBold = false;
  bool _isItalic = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Custom Rich Text Editor')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          // TextField to input text
          TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Type something here...'),
            onChanged: (value) => setState(() {}),
          ),
          // Buttons to apply styles
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.format_bold),
                color: _isBold ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _isBold = !_isBold),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.format_italic),
                color: _isItalic ? Colors.blue : Colors.black,
                onPressed: () => setState(() => _isItalic = !_isItalic),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          // Displaying styled text using RichText
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  text: _controller.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: _isBold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                    fontStyle: _isItalic ? FontStyle.italic : FontStyle.normal,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Advanced: Combine Quill with Custom Styling

If Quill almost meets your needs but lacks some customization:
1.  Fork the Flutter Quill repository.
2.  Modify its source code to fit your custom requirements (e.g., add specific formatting options or UI tweaks).
3.  Add custom toolbar buttons for different styles.
Common Issues and Solutions
Plugins not rendering correctly - Check for platform-specific dependencies (like web or desktop support).
Missing formatting features - Customize the toolbar or extend the base functionality of the plugin.
Styles not applied dynamically - Ensure the editor rebuilds on style change (e.g., using setState).
*My Best Flutter Quil))
